# access dynamically generated id

Tags: jquery, html

Say you are generating an id this way

```
var id = Date.now();
$("#someID").click(function(){
  var content = '<input type="text" id ="test[' + id + '].address"';
  $('#contentArea').append(content);
});
```

`SomeID` might be clicked a couple times thus generating many inputs, how can you trigger the `onkeydown` event on each?

Comment: Use a class assigned to each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you what to catch on change event of dynamically created input.
So you can add `class="my_class"` to input select class and use :

```
$('.my_class').on('change',function(){...});
```

Use `$(this)` to access the current input.

Comment: You're right j08691, this answer should be combined with your one.

Comment: it will work on dynamically created here is an example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/EPMVq/1/)

Comment: @zZD1M0NZz - Your example fiddle is inaccurate. You're not creating the inner event handler until the outer one is clicked. It fails otherwise http://jsfiddle.net/sUpV6/

Comment: there was no specification on when the event should be binded to the input

Comment: @j08691 Your fiddle adds too many handlers. After pressing Create twice, the first `<input>` has 2 copies of the handler. You should either use event delegation like in your main answer, or change `$('.my_class').on(...);` to `$('#test[' + id + '].address').on(...);`. (And for this to work, `id` should be set inside the click handler, so that the IDs are actually different - it's probably safe to say this is what OP intended anyway.)

Comment: @DavidKnipe - My fiddle in the above comment isn't a solution, it points out the flaw in this user's answer.

Comment: @j08691 But it's arguably just as bad as the original post. And it should be pointed out that it's wrong, since it's not obvious. Furthermore it may not be obvious to OP how to fix it, especially since as I pointed out the IDs are all the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .on()'s event delegation syntax:

```
$(document).on('keydown','input[id^="test"]',function(){...});
```

Ideally you want to target an existing ancestor in the DOM closer than just `document`, but that will still work.